# When using JWT for route authentication, the page stays stuck in the same place

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently working on modifying a project. The front-end uses Vue 2.0 and the back-end uses Node.js Express. I'm using the JWT approach by setting all pages except the login page to require authentication, and then setting up permission verification in router.beforeEach(). If a user wants to access a sensitive page, the locally stored token is sent to the server for verification. Through testing, the back-end API is able to correctly verify the token. However, I'm currently facing a problem where the router doesn't redirect when requesting other pages, and some errors are being reported.On browser console it shows like below:

```
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2316 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at eval (main.js?1c90:158:1)
    at iterator (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2362:1)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2087:1)
    at step (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2091:1)
    at runQueue (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2095:1)
    at HashHistory.confirmTransition (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2392:1)
    at HashHistory.transitionTo (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2260:1)
    at HashHistory.push (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2715:1)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?fe87:3036:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWM7N.png)

Here is my code:

#### main.js

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(res => res.meta.requireAuth)) { //if the page need to be authorized
        let isLogin = getStore("isLogin");
        let role = getStore("role");
        let token = getStore("token")//get local token
        let num = Vue.cookie.get("num");
        store.dispatch('setStatus');
        if(!token) {
            router.push({name:"login"});//if there is no token on local storage, redirect to login page
        }else {
            authenticateRole(token).then(data => {// The code that verify the token. Send the token to back-end server. The implementation is below.
                console.log(data)
                if(data.code === 0) {//if verify successfully, server will response a 0 code .
//From this point on, the code will not work properly in the DEBUG mode 
                    if(to.name !== "login"){
                        if (!isLogin || data.role !== "boss" && data.role !== "admin") {
                            router.push({name: "login"}); //if is not login, redirerct to login page 
                        }else{
                            if(to.name === "admin" && data.role !== "boss" ){
                                router.push({name: "login"});
                            }else{
                                next();
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        next();
                    }
                }
                else router.push({name: "login"}) //if the code is not zero
            })
        }
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
});
```

#### api.js

```
export const server = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://" + SERVER_IP + ":8000/",
    timeout: 25000,
    withCredentials: true
});

export const authenticateRole = (jwt) => {
    server.post("/authenticate",{
        token: jwt
    })
}
```

#### router.js

```
path: "index",
name: "index",
component: index,
meta: {
   requireAuth: true
},
```

Comment: You should use `next(route name)` at all places where you're currently using `router.push(...)`. Also, an easier approach would be to allow naviation to all routes (get rid of `beforeEach` guard) and simply rely on the backend to respond with 403 on each AJAX request whose JWT token does not have the required permission(s). Then you can simply show an error alert/toast when you receive 403 from the API - "Not enough permissions".

Answer (score 0):

In your api.js you don't return anything from `authenticateRole` function. This way axios's promise is not exposed to the code in router. Just add the return statement, or remove the curly braces:

```
export const authenticateRole = (jwt) => server.post("/authenticate",{
    token: jwt
})
```